# re-order vector<std::unique_ptr<X>> given a vector<const X*>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, unique-ptr

I have a `vector<std::unique_ptr<X>>` and a `vector<const X*>` that contain the same set of pointers, but in a different order. I want to have the vector of unique pointers be ordered exactly like the vector of const pointers.

One way I could do it is like this:

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<X>> uniq_ptrs;
vector<const X*> const_ptrs;
vector<std::unique_ptr<X>> tmp(uniq_ptrs.size());

hash_map<const X*, int> indices;
for (int i = 0; i < const_ptrs->size(); ++i) {
  indices[const_ptrs[i]] = i;
}
for (std::unique_ptr<X>& uniq_ptr : uniq_ptrs) {
  tmp[indices[uniq_ptr.get()]].swap(uniq_ptr);
}
uniq_ptrs.swap(tmp)
```

an in-place version, still with hash_map:

```
vector<const X*> const_ptrs;

hash_map<const X*, int> indices;
for (int i = 0; i < const_ptrs.size(); ++i) {
  indices[const_ptrs[i]] = i;
}
for (int i = 0; i < const_ptrs.size(); ++i) {
  std::swap(uniq_ptrs[i], uniq_ptrs[indices[const_ptrs[i]]]);
}
```

But I hope there is a nicer way that doesn't involve a temporary vector a hash map and two passes over the data.

Comment: The auxiliary structure affords you linear complexity on the rearrangement. Without it you'd need to traverse the range more often.

Comment: Since you are just dealing with pointers , can you not create a new vector<std::unique_ptr<X>> looping through vector<const X*> const_ptrs.

Comment: @jayadev, I'll have to remove the constness with casting though.

Comment: your in-place version looks completely flawed, sure there aren't typos there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `const_ptrs` contains the *same* pointers as the `uniq_ptrs`, there is no need to use the latter at all, and **no need for a temporary** either. However, you must be careful not to delete the objects.

```
// release the unique_ptrs of their ownership
for(auto&x : uniq_ptrs)
    x.release();
// fill the array with the pointers in another order
uniq_ptrs.clear();
for(auto x : const_ptrs)
    uniq_ptrs.emplace_back(const_cast<X*>(x));   // const_cast okay here
```

Comment: Worth noting that this relies on the fact that all instances of `std::default_delete<X>` are equivalent (the type has no state), so it doesn't matter that you're losing and re-creating the deleters.

Comment: As mentioned before `const_cast<>` is safe in this context - it's the same set of pointers, just in a different order. +1 for being readable and using emplace_back() :)

Answer (score 0):

If performance were no issue:

```
auto idx_of = [&](X const* p) {
    return std::distance(begin(const_ptrs), std::find(begin(const_ptrs), end(const_ptrs), p)); 
};
std::sort(begin(uniq_ptrs), end(uniq_ptrs), [&](std::unique_ptr<X> const& a, std::unique_ptr<X> const& b) {
            return idx_of(a.get()) < idx_of(b.get());
        });
```

If performance *is* a concern, use your intermediate map:

```
hash_map<const X*, int> indices;
for (auto i = 0u; i < const_ptrs.size(); ++i) {
    indices[const_ptrs[i]] = i;
}

std::sort(begin(uniq_ptrs), end(uniq_ptrs), [&](std::unique_ptr<X> const& a, std::unique_ptr<X> const& b) {
            return indices[ a.get() ] < indices[ b.get() ];
        });
```

---If you're absolutely sure about the sets of pointers matching, you could cheat and create completely new unique_ptrs on the fly.--- Hmm won't work because of the const, like you said.

> **Update** Just drop the const, if the performance is leading here. If you know the objects aren't *actually* const, you can employ the evil `const_cast<>`

See all three approaches: **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/712203748850001c)**

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

template <typename K, typename V>
using hash_map = std::unordered_map<K,V>;

struct X{};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<X>> uniq_ptrs;
    std::vector<const X*> const_ptrs;

    // naive approach, no performance worries
    auto idx_of = [&](X const* p) {
        return std::distance(begin(const_ptrs), std::find(begin(const_ptrs), end(const_ptrs), p)); 
    };
    std::sort(begin(uniq_ptrs), end(uniq_ptrs), [&](std::unique_ptr<X> const& a, std::unique_ptr<X> const& b) {
                return idx_of(a.get()) < idx_of(b.get());
            });

    // less naive approach, no performance worries
    hash_map<const X*, int> indices;
    for (auto i = 0u; i < const_ptrs.size(); ++i) {
        indices[const_ptrs[i]] = i;
    }

    std::sort(begin(uniq_ptrs), end(uniq_ptrs), [&](std::unique_ptr<X> const& a, std::unique_ptr<X> const& b) {
                return indices[ a.get() ] < indices[ b.get() ];
            });

    // cheating! only not UB if you know the objects aren't "physically" const
    assert(const_ptrs.size() == uniq_ptrs.size());
    for (auto i = 0u; i < const_ptrs.size(); ++i) {
        uniq_ptrs[i].release();
        uniq_ptrs[i].reset(const_cast<X*>(const_ptrs[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The second code snippet is O(n log n) since it sorts, so I believe it would be slower than the second code snippet in my question.

Comment: @thesamet I don't see how your inplace version works (it will not compile, because `i` is not in scope and cannot be swapped, either). Conceptually, though, you're sorting anyway (it's the essence of your algorithm), and there's also implicit sorting in the hash_map. I suspect the `hash_map` insertion times are going to dominate the runtime for any non-trivial n here. I suggest you benchmark this in your _real application_ to see whether it matters/what works. **Drop the const** if you need it for performance.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I fixed my 2nd example though so it's correct, though I didn't try to run it.

Comment: @thesamet I've added the dubious `const_cast<>` version, in case you really want to have your cake and eat it. I can see myself getting this past code-review if performance actually demands it, and with proper comment documentation and impact analysis.

Comment: @sehe I'm confused as to why the `const_cast` version is dubious here. We **know** (via assertion from the OP) that `const_ptrs` and `uniq_ptrs` contain the same pointers, and hence cannot possibly be pointing to `const` objects.

Comment: @Walter well, it's not UB, if _that's_ what you mean. I tend to look a bit further than UB for code review, though. `const_cast<>` is dubious, almost by definition. In this case, like I said, I could talk it past code-review.